# Days back VIP membership

Tags: php, cron

My table "users" has a column "vip" and "vipudlob".

vipudlob = the timestamp where the "vip membership" expired.

I will make some kind of cronjob which sends a "reminder" to users, when there is 7 days left. And update user(s) when the "vipudlob" is expired to vip=0, vipudlob=0

Can any good-guy help me with this?

i tried something like this, but doesn't work properly

```
if ( time() >= $row['udlob']):
    echo "Your membership expired"
else: //still working
   if ( date("d", $row['udlob']) <= 7):
         echo "7 days back!"
   endif
endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the Currant timestamp using time function then Check if it's expired

For example

$currunt_timestamp = time();
$membership_expire = "";

```
if (($currunt_timestamp - $membership_expire) < 600) // (600 = 60*10 seconds = 10 minutes) 
{
       echo "No Expired";
} else {

echo "expired";

}
```

Comment: 600 because if there is more than 10 minutes of gap between the expiry time and current time